# Случайное изменение шрифта и его размера в listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, текст, listbox

У меня есть простая форма, которая при нажатии кнопки увеличивает число в label1 на одну единицу и цвета текста меняется на рандомный (из массива **co**). Код следующий:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Color[] co = new Color[5] {Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Orange, Color.Purple}; 
    int a;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        a = rnd.Next(0, 4);
        label1.ForeColor = co[a];

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
        i++;
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "0";
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** можно ли подобное сделать для изменения **шрифта и его размера** и как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Label есть свойство шрифт (**Font**). Ему можно присвоить новый шрифт следующим образом:

```
// fonts - string массив с названиями шрифтов
// newSize - новый размер шрифта
// rand - случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до fonts.Length
label1.Font = new Font(fonts[rand], newSize);
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, как необходимо после объявления массивов со шрифтами и размерами, объявить случайный выбор значения из них. Можете поподробней уточнить?

Comment: string fonts[] = new string [] {"Arial", "Comic Sans", "Calibri" и т.д. }

Comment: randomIndex = rnd.Next(0, fonts.length);

Comment: int newSize = размер который вам нужен

Comment: label1.Font = new Font(fonts[randomeIndex], newSize);